# What's the simplest way to build express.js server with swagger

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger

I used to use hapi.js as my framework. To generate documentation, [hapi-swagger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-swagger-plugins) is used. It is really simple. I don't need any specification document. All I had to do is registering it as a plugin in my hapi.js server.

When I switch to express.js, I can't find anything similar. I found a couple popular swagger modules. All of them require a specification document.

Is there a way to make a self-document swagger UI for express.js server?

If not, what's the best way to make a swagger UI? I only need the UI to show all of my routes and their params and do some simple tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LoopBack (http://loopback.io/getting-started/) and follow the instructions.

But **be aware**, you need to keep writing the documentation of each file by your own.